# Block navigation action in onNavigationStateChange in StackNavigator

Tags: react-navigation

In my StackNavigator I want to sometimes block a navigation action. I thought to use `onNavigationStateChange` however it is not working.

Simple example:

```
render() {
    return <Stack onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigate} />
}

handleNavigate = (stateOld, stateNew, action) => {
    return false; // block it
}
```

However it is not blocking it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use **onShouldStartLoadWithRequest** instead

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest

Comment: This is webview. I was asking for `react-navigation`